# JS Code Deploying on Web

Tags: android, node.js, web, coffeescript, location

I am a junior mobile developer who is working on a location tracking app for android. I want to monitor location of people using android tracking app on web for which I have found this code on [github](https://github.com/techmagic-team/track-my-location/tree/develop/track-location/web) written in Coffee script. I am total noob when it comes to web terminology or tool

I dont know how to show output of this code on web/browser. Can any one give me simple bullets on how to use this code and see output.

Answer (score 4):

Download and install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Go to the code Directory, ie.
`cd ~/track-my-location-develop/track-location/web`

and run the following command: `npm install && npm start`

After thats done, open the url http://localhost:4000 on your browser

You will get a list of devices available,Get any of those user id and track the device by navigating to : http://localhost:4000/track/:objectId

eg: http://localhost:4000/track/Simulator

Refer to app.coffee file for further details regarding the routes available.

Now you could use these WebServices within your android application to do your desired task.